# How to calculate the volume of intersection between a cube and a sphere (probability)

Tags: probability

Essentially the green cube with each side = 1, is a probability space and I have been asked to find $$Pr(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\le 1)$$ which is the purple sphere.

I can tell that from the graph only 1/8th of the sphere is in the probability space and hence $$pr = \frac{1}{8}*\frac{4}{3}\pi$$ but how could I algebraically work it out?
[image]

Comment: Which graph are you talking about?

Comment: Just updated, couldn't embed image coz I am new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation would be
$$Pr(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1) = \int_{0}^1 \int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2} \, \mathrm{d} y \, \mathrm{d} x \\
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} \left[y \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} + (1-x^2) \arcsin \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right]_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x\\
= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} (1-x^2) \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4} [x - x^3/3]_0^1 \\
= \frac{\pi}{6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

"Telling from the graph" is the best way to do the problem. You correctly noted that the important volume is $1/8$ of the sphere.

There's no need for an "algebraic" solution.